# Optional parameter in WHERE clause

Tags: t-sql

I have a query something like this:

```
declare @LastName varchar(50), @firstletter varchar(50)

set @LastName ='%Jones%'

select * from tblSample where Last_Name like @LastName
```

This query returns all records from tblSample where the Last_Name field is LIKE the value in the variable @LastName

Sometimes the results can contain too many records, such as when the last name is Jones, or Smith, etc. In those cases I want to enter the first initial of the first name. However, So if I had a variable like:

```
declare @name varchar(50), @firstletter varchar(50)

set @FirstInitial ='T%'

select * from tblSample where Last_Name like @LastName AND First_Name Like @FirstInitial
```

How would I condition the where clause to only look for the value in First_Name if it is not ''.

tod

I don't know what to do, so I didn't try anything yet.

Comment: `select * from tblSample where Last_Name like @LastName AND (@FirstInitial == '' OR First_Name Like @FirstInitial)`

Comment: `if @FirstInitial = '' set @FirstInitial = '%';` before the `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming no value would be supplied for @FirstInitial unless required and therefore @FirstInital would be NULL then the following will work

```
SELECT * 
    FROM tblSample
    WHERE Last_Name LIKE @LastName
      AND (First_Name LIKE @FirstInitial OR @FirstInitial  IS NULL)
```

Comment: This is a clean method that I prefer myself.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure I got it, but if you want to filter by `First_name` only if your `@FirstInitial` is not '', I believe something like this would do:

```sql
SELECT * FROM tblSample WHERE Last_Name LIKE @LastName
AND (
    CASE
        WHEN @FirstInitial <> '' THEN First_Name LIKE @FirstInitial
        ELSE true
    END
)
```

You could change the query and do `WHEN First_Name <> '' THEN First_Name LIKE @FirstInitial` if that's what you need.

More on how the CASE keyword works in T-SQL - in documentation [CASE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

Comment: A [`case`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) expression cannot return a [boolean](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/comparison-operators-transact-sql?#boolean-data-type) data type. This is "documented" by virtue of [Return Types](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?#return-types) referencing [Data Type Precedence](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql) which does not list `boolean` as a data type. ...

Comment: ... You could still use a `case`, but it becomes rather clumsy, e.g.: `... and ( case when @FirstInitial = '' then 1 when First_Name like @FirstInitial then 1 else 0 end = 1 )`. Readability and performance don't benefit from the added complexity.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this, where you check for the occurance of the string

```
declare @LastName varchar(50), @FirstInitial varchar(50)

set @FirstInitial ='T%'

select * from tblSample where Last_Name like @LastName AND First_Name Like 
  CASE WHEN @FirstInitial = '.' THEN First_Name ELSE @FirstInitial END
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put the following statement before the `SELECT`

```sql
if @FirstInitial = ''
    set @FirstInitial = '%';
```